# How to check equality of child objects in a parent ArrayList using the childrens overridden equals() method

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Hi would really appreciate some help figuring out how to check equality here.

So I have a parent class : person, and sub classes: man, woman, both sub classes have equals over ridden to be equal if man objects make the same amount of money per year, and woman objects are the same age. In the parent class person: I have an arraylist with 5 man and woman objects each, some of them would be considered equal as defined in each child classes equals(Object o) method. How would I sift through the arraylist to print which are equal?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Person
{
    private ArrayList<Person> people;

    public Person()
    {
        people = new ArrayList<>();

        people.add(new Man("John Smith", 51000));
        people.add(new Man("Who Ever", 0));
        people.add(new Man("Brent Groff", 51000));
        people.add(new Man("Adam Nothing", 29000));
        people.add(new Man("Bob Dob", 90000));

        people.add(new Woman("Jane Smith", 45));
        people.add(new Woman("Holly Way", 60));
        people.add(new Woman("Anna Sheroka", 28));
        people.add(new Woman("Fara Daniels", 28));
        people.add(new Woman("Minie Do", 19));
    }

    public void displayAllEqualPeople()
    {
        for (int i  = 0; i < people.size() ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1 ; j < people.size() ; j++)
            {
                if (people.get(i) instanceof Man)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will group people by salary/age.

```
Map<String, Person> men = people.stream()
    .filter(p -> p instanceof Man)
    .map(p -> (Man) p)
    .collect(groupingBy(Man::getSalary));

Map<String, Person> women = people.stream()
    .filter(p -> p instanceof Woman)
    .map(p -> (Woman) p)
    .collect(groupingBy(Woman::getAge));
```